# Azure DNS - reboot - reconfigure network machines

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have configured a virtual network and have a DNS server (by doing DCPromo on a VM). Somewhere I read that this DNS server being "first" in the network will get a IP address of x.x.x.4, So I assumed that, spinned three more machines and then joined them to the domain. When doing the joining, I choose in the network adapter setting 10.0.0.4 as the DNS server but left the IP addresses empty so that DHCP can assign them.

When I reboot my DNS server, I see that the machines I assigned to the domain have all lost their DNS address (resolves some arbitrary 169 series) and I forced to re-enter the domain DNS server again.

1. Am I not supposed to rebooting DNS in Azure?
2. If I do have to reboot (say windows update), does that mean that I have to reconfigure ALL the machines to the DNS server addresses AGAIN?

Cheers
VJ

Comment: Have you created a virtual network on Azure? coz if you have created that before even creating the virtual machine you get to choose the IP address of the machine so the ip address is assigned by you. I didn't get what you mean by it get x.x.x.4 coz you can assign that. in you virtual network you can easily choose your DNS server

Comment: @MPAKBAZ - thanks for answering. I have created the DNS as the first machine, no issues there. In fact all was fine, until I rebooted the DNS, once I rebooted, I logged to one of the VM (part of domain), did a IPCONFIG/ALL, I saw that the 10.0.0.4 was lost, and there was some other DNS. So question is, can I reboot DNS and If I do, should I redo the steps of assigning 10.0.0.4 to ALL sub machines in domain.

Comment: Are all machines on the same subnet? I had difficulties with azure network as well specially when it comes to different subnet. I remeber I could not ping from one machine in Subnet 1 to another machine in Subnet 2, however recently I saw the did some modification to azure network. Regarding the behavior you said, for me is weird as well...

Comment: yes, they are in the same subnet. I could even access \\servername\share without any issues, alas, all till the reboot.

Comment: Please provide full network configuration for the Azure Virtual Network and then explain how you configure the virtual machines. You may refer to this blog post: http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/05/active-directory-in-azure-step-by-step.html where I explain how to configure everything. And it all works fine even across reboots.

Comment: @astaykov - I have already referred to the blog :-), incidentally, what i have done is, in the Azure portal, in Network, registered the dns server with the IP, 10.0.0.4, rebooted all the machines, now even though, the DNS is NOT explicitly configured in the adapter settings, IPCONFIG/ALL reveals that they are under my domain. I Hope i did the correct thing here ?

Comment: sure. you shall **never** set static IP/DNS settings in your Azure VMs. Let Azure Virtual Network manage this for you. And yes, setting 10.0.0.4 for DNS Server is correct as long as you plan to put DNS server VM in this subnet (10.0.0.0/XX).

Comment: Thanks @astaykov, I am not sure how to mark your comment as answer. If you can create a new post as reply, i will mark it as answer.